# Why does this std::sort predicate fail when the class is inside main()?

Tags: c++, templates, stl

This is a much simplified repro which illustrates how `class Predicate` delcared outside `main()` works but when the exact code appears inline as `class InlinePredicate` the compiler can't match `std::sort`.  The strange thing is that you can pass *anything* as the third argument to `std::sort` (say, integer 7) and you'll just get a compile error when it does not support the `operator ()` that `sort` expects.  But when I pass `pred2` below it doesn't match at all:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Predicate {
public:
    bool operator () (const pair<string,int>& a, const pair<string,int>& b)
    {
        return a.second < b.second;
    }
};

int
main()
{
    vector<pair<string, int> > a;

    Predicate pred;
    sort(a.begin(), a.end(), pred);

    class InlinePredicate {
    public:
        bool operator () (const pair<string,int>& a, const pair<string,int>& b)
        {
            return a.second < b.second;
        }
    } pred2;
    sort(a.begin(), a.end(), pred2);

    return 0;
}
```

> repro.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
>
> repro.cc:30: error: no matching function for call to ‘sort(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator, std::allocator >, int>*, std::vector, std::allocator >, int>, std::allocator, std::allocator >, int> > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator, std::allocator >, int>*, std::vector, std::allocator >, int>, std::allocator, std::allocator >, int> > > >, main()::InlinePredicate&)’

Comment: As a side note: your operator should probably be const `bool operator()(const pair<string,int>& a, const pair<string,int>& b) **const**`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C++03, local classes have no linkage and consequently cannot be used as template arguments (§14.3.1/2).

In C++0x, this limitation has been removed and your code would compile as-is.

Comment: You should probably still make the predicate's operator `const`, as `sort` might require that.

Comment: It does compile with `g++ -std=c++0x` for GCC 4.5 (not 4.3, and I don't have 4.4 handy)

Answer (score 5):

In versions of C++ prior to C++0x, classes declared inside functions cannot appear in template parameters. Your invocation of `sort` implicitly instantiates it with a template parameter set to `InlinePredicate`, which is illegal.

You may want to consider using either C++0x (with GCC, pass `--std=c++0x`; in C++0x this code will work as-is, or you can use anonymous functions instead), or [`boost::lambda`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/lambda.html). With `boost::lambda`, it would look like this:

```
using namespace boost::lambda;

sort(a.begin(), a.end(), _1 < _2);
```

Comment: Note that as of Boost 1.47, Boost.Lambda is officially deprecated in favor of [Boost.Phoenix v3](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/phoenix/). Consequently, new code would be much better off using Phoenix instead of Lambda (and the syntax you showed for the `sort` call would remain identical).

Comment: @ildjarn, oh great, _yet another_ C++03 anonymous function hack to learn... :)

Comment: But a much more powerful one, definitely worth it. :-] Even in C++0x, I tend to use Phoenix functors over C++0x lambdas about half the time, since they're polymorphic.