# how to define a functor inside a function

Tags: c++

Sometimes, I need some functor-helper to manipulate list. I try to keep the scope as local as possible.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    struct Square
    {
        int operator()(int x)
        {
            return x*x;
        }
    };

    int a[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    int b[5];

    transform(a, a+5, b, Square());

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
        cout<<a[i]<<" "<<b[i]<<endl;
}
```

---

```
hello.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
hello.cpp:18:34: error: no matching function for call to ‘transform(int [5], int*, int [5], main()::Square)’
```

If I move `Square` out of `main()`, it's ok.

Comment: [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880077/why-does-this-stdsort-predicate-fail-when-the-class-is-inside-main).

Comment: Hmm... I copied the code from the question and tried it on VS2010, and it works fine... :-\ .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot do it. However, in some cases, you can use `boost::bind` or `boost::lambda` libraries to build functors without declaring an outside structure. Also, if you have a recent compiler (such as gcc version 4.5) you can enable the new C++0x features which allow you to use lambda expressions, allowing such syntax:

`transform(a, a+5, b, [](int x) -> int { return x*x; });`

Answer (score 6):

In the current standard (C++98/03) local classes (local functors) can't be used as classes as a template parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by several answers here, C++ pre-0x cannot use local types as template arguments. What I usually do to circumvent this issue (besides hoping the projects I work on will move to C++0x soon) is to put the respective local class as a private nested class in the class of the member function that needs this functor. Alternatively, I sometimes put the functor in the respective `.cpp` file, imagining that it is cleaner (and slightly faster to compile).

Answer (score -1):

I think the best answer to this question is "Use a [functional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) programming language".

Comment: Tags are part of the question, so although that's an answer to a question somewhat similar to this one, I don't think it's an answer to this one.